# Get data from DB

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to get data in JavaFX application from database. But during this time the application freezes.

```
Map<String, List<DataObj>> dbData = ConnectedAgents.generateDataObj(ac);
```

I tested this code and in first look it looks good. But is this the beast way to do background database operations?

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Map<String, List<DataObj>> dbData = ConnectedAgents.generateDataObj(ac);
            }
        });
```

Can you tell me what is the best way to do database operations in JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Platform.runLater(...)` does not run things in a background thread. It actually does entirely the opposite: it executes the provided `Runnable`'s `run()` method on the FX Application Thread. You can use `Platform.runLater(...)` to update the UI as a result of code that is run on a background thread, but there are usually better ways to do this.

You should use a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to achieve what you want here.

```
final Task<Map<String, List<DataObj>>> dataGenerationTask = new Task<Map<String, List<DataObj>>>() {
    @Override
    public Map<String, List<DataObj>> call() throws Exception {
        return ConnectedAgents.generateDataObj(ac);
    }
};

dataGenerationTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        Map<String, List<DataObj>> dbData = dataGenerationTask.getValue();
        // you can safely update the UI with the dbData here....
    }
});

dataGenerationTask.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        Throwable t = dataGenerationTask.getException();
        // handle errors here, if needed
    }
});

Thread thread = new Thread(dataGenerationTask);
thread.setDaemon(true); // this thread won't prevent shutdown of the application
thread.start();
```

Comment: In general when Task finishes what happens? Is it destroyed or it's in sleeping state?

Comment: It moves to the "succeeded" state (or "failed" state if it completes with an exception). It's a one-off task, so you can't restart it. Obviously, it gets garbage collected in the usual way as long as you let it go out of scope.